# OOP static variable standards

Tags: c++, variables, static, private, public

I am working on a project in C++ but I can see this happening in any other Object Oriented Language.  I need a static variable in a class and I am wondering if the standard rules apply to static variables as to non-static variables in that within a class they should be private and changed/accessed with accessors and mutators of any variable of that type rather than being public and accessed directly by code outside the class.  My gut tells me that static variables in a class should still be private but most code that I have searched for the answer to (generic static variable examples) have had the static variables public.

Since I am assuming that static variables should be private, what are some, if they exists examples of when a static variable in a class should be public?

Comment: C++ in general doesn't do OOP as a matter of principle, it's generally a matter of good design. Don't use accessors "just because". The same holds for static members.

Comment: This is the reason of my dilemma.  I am mostly an embedded C developer by trade and have no issue with not using OOP standards.  However, the OOP heavy developers get mad when you break OOP rules, even in C++.  To keep things kosher I want to get an idea of what is canonical in C++ and other OOP languages.

Comment: @TheWinterSnow: For all practical purposes, "OOP" is so vague that it can mean nothing and everything. There are no established "rules", and there is no official definition of what is "kosher" and what isn't. Your "OOP heavy developers" sound like people who want to write Java or C# in C++. That's already a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: Outside of the single-purpose world of the embedded program, “good practices” and (non-constant) “static variables” are nearly contradictory: a `static` variable is just a global variable that, if not `public`, is dressed up as a set of functions.  It still has all the lifetime, thread-safety, action-at-a-distance, and composability issues of any global.

Comment: Yeah Christian Hackl I am a computer science major in college and I am having the issue in that every class I take the professors push hardcore OOP standards in the assignments even in C++.  I have worked in the field for a couple of years and have seen C, javascript and Python code but not C++ so I wanted to get an idea of how practical C++ developers write code